# Clarification of some doubts on the definition of submatrix

Tags: matrices, definition

I don't fully understand how I can choose a submatrix in a matrix. Judging from this definition and picture (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Submatrix.html), I would assume that you can't pick as a submatrix \begin{pmatrix}a_{1 1} & a_{1 2} \\ a_{4 1}&a_{4 2}\end{pmatrix} or \begin{pmatrix}a_{1 1} & a_{1 2} \\ a_{4 3}&a_{4 4}\end{pmatrix}, but is that true?
More in general, my question is:

> can you give a clear complete definition of submatrix and explain precisely how do I 
>   pick a submatrix?

Note: I'm mostly interested in this for the purpose of finding a non-zero determinant submatrix for calculating the rank of a matrix.

Comment: The first one is a submatrix, the second one isn't. A submatrix of a given matrix is the matrix you obtain by suppressing some columns and rows. For the first one in your question, you'd suppress rows $2$ and $3$ and columns $3$ and $4$. Can you transform this description in a more rigorous definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your link a submatrix is just a *block* of another matrix. So this is just a connected 'rectangle' of numbers of the original matrix, that means (as you already assumed) that you cannot skip rows or columns.

But if you consider following link, you *can* skip rows or columns, that means you can construct any submatrix by *deleting* whole columns and rows of the original matrix.

https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Submatrix

When looking at determinants, you probably mean the *minors*. These are submatrices that you get by deleting exaclty one row and one column of the original (square) matrix

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29