# Write all sub matrices of $\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\ 4&5&6\\ 7&8&9\\ \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Write all submatrices of  $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\ 4&5&6\\ 7&8&9\\
>  \end{bmatrix}$

**Here is my answre:**

To solve this problem I wrote all $1\times1$ ,$1\times2$ , $1\times3$, $2\times1$ , $2\times2$ , $2\times3$ , $ 3\times1$ ,$3\times2$ , $3\times3$ matrices from $A$:

$1\times1$ matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}5
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}6
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}7
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}8
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}9
\end{bmatrix}$$

$1\times2$matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2&3
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4&5
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}5&6
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}7&8
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}8&9
\end{bmatrix}$$

$1\times3$ matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4&5&6
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}7&8&9
\end{bmatrix}$$

$2\times1$ matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\4
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4\\7
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
2\\5\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
5\\8\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
3\\6\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
6\\9\end{bmatrix}$$

$2\times2$ matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\4&5
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\5&6
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4&5\\7&8
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}5&6\\8&9
\end{bmatrix}$$

$2\times3$ matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4&5&6\\7&8&9
\end{bmatrix}$$

$3\times1$ matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\\7
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\\8
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3\\6\\9
\end{bmatrix}$$

$3\times2$ matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\4&5\\7&8
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\5&6\\8&9
\end{bmatrix}$$

$3\times3$ matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\ 4&5&6\\ 7&8&9\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Is my answer right? (did I write all sub matrices of $A$ correctly?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found them all according to [wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Submatrix.html). However, when we speak about submatrices we have to state *which kind of submatrix* we are considering, for example, look at this [definition](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Submatrix). This last definition is the most frequently used. (The first kind is called *block* submatrix).

So, at the end of the day, you found all *block* submatrices (which I frankly think was what you were asked to do). Anyway, you should check the definition given in your material to be sure.

Here there is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120315/clarification-of-some-doubts-on-the-definition-of-submatrix) if you want to read about it.

Comment: Yes. it is confusing. the definition given to us is: if we delete some rows or columns of the  matrix we get a sub matrix of the original one. So I think I missed many matrices.

Comment: Indeed, it's always important to check the definitions in case of confusion. I think this solves your question :)

Answer (score 4):

Nope. [Submatrices](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=submatrix) don't have to be "connected", so you're missing, among others,
\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\7&9
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: And empty matrix is missing also.

Answer (score 1):

No. You will get all submatrices by deleting some (0 to 3) rows and columns. Property of elements "to be in the same column with" will be preserved (the same for rows).

Comment: I haven't been taught about empty matrix. do you think it is a good idea to consider it as a sub matrix too?

Comment: Well, depends on definition. In many implementations empty matrix is not necessary, but sonetimes it is useful to write an equation, formulae or theorem in more compact way.